# How to customize the "description" of the manytomany inline in the admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have those extremely simple models:

```
class Activity(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Person(BaseModel):
    activities = models.ManyToManyField('Activity', related_name='persons')
```

In the `admin.py` I've made an inline for this and it works, like this:

```
class PersonActivitiesInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profession.persons.through
    fk_name = 'person'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PersonActivitiesInlineAdmin, )
```

My problem is that the string describing the inline, in the admin interface, is like

```
 Profession: Person_activities object (831)
 Profession: Person_activities object (832)
 Profession: Person_activities object (835)
 Profession: Person_activities object (838)
```

So how to customize the "description" of the manytomany inline in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to explicitly create the join model for the many-to-many relationship of `Person` and `Activity` by using [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and add description to it:

```
class Activity(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Person(BaseModel):
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(
        Activity,
        related_name='persons',
        through='PersonActivity'  # Use PersonActivity for join model
    )

class PersonActivity(BaseModel):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # Your custom description field
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        # The admin automatically renders the string representation of the model
        # e.g. Person_activities object (838)

        # Thus you can return your custom description in order to display it
        return self.description
```

Comment: I've already tried that but Django explicitely forbids to change this once a ManyToMany field has been created.